# Java Regex to replace only certain apostrophes from input files

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall, inverted-index

I'm writing code to construct inverted indices from a large number of input files. I've been able to parse the input using

`String[] words = value.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", " ").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");`

I ran into some trouble when replacing special characters with the empty string, since that resulted in some words getting merged together, so I replaced them with whitespace in the above code. However, using the above code still doesn't give the output I want, since it separates words with apostrophes into two words

The input files I'm using are varied, some are shakespeare poetry, others are play scripts, etc.
I'm having trouble figuring out how to include certain apostrophes in my words but not others.

For example:

the input

`'twas, 't,[order'd], king's, o', 'Brutus!', ''At`

should return

`'twas 't order'd king's o' Brutus At`

In other words, I want to keep apostrophes in the case of preceding or ending single apostrophes and words that contain an apostrophe followed by a single letter, while getting rid of a pair of single apostrophes around a word or double apostrophes preceding or following a word. Is there any way to do this or something close to this using a series of regex?

Comment: Use `"[^A-z'\u2018\u2019\u201B\u2032]"`: that are all single quotes. For English there should not be need for `"(?u)!(\\pL|[\'\u2018\u2019\u201B\u2032])"`: Unicode mode, not letters or quotes.

Comment: (Quoted text is a different level.)

Comment: This is a messy question, as it is really two questions, one dealing with apostrophes and the other dealing with characters other than letters, spaces and apostrophies. Regarding the apostrophes, I don't think the larger problem you are dealing with can be addressed in its entirty with a regular expression. One reason is that some English words contain two or more apostrophes, such as "'twasn't"...

Comment: It might be clearer to frame the question in terms of the single quotes you wish to remove, rather than ones to keep. For example you might want to remove single quotes that surround words that contain only letters an at most one apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Replace all commas with spaces (without creating double-spaces)
- Remove all non “keeper” chars
- Remove quotes from quoted terms

```
str = str.replaceAll(" *, *", " ")
  .replaceAll("[^\\w' !]", "")
  .replaceAll("'(\\S*)'", "$1");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/sGB1du).

`\w` means “any word char”
`\S` means “any non-whitespace char”

If you want to keep more chars, adjust the regex accordingly.